# Converting Date to String is missing AM/PM designator

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, date-conversion

I have a Date object which contains #3/10/2016 2:43:04 AM#
When I try to convert to string, AM/PM (in this case AM) designator is missed.

For example:

```
Dim date1 As Date 
date1 = #3/10/2016 2:43:04 AM#
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt"))
```

displays:

```
"10/03/2016 2:43:04"
```

Also I have tried:

```
date1.ToString()
```

and it displays the same result as before.

I want toString conversion displays the same, that is: "3/10/2016 2:43:04 AM"

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try `DateTime` data type? Also if you have it already why would you assign it to date and back out to a string?

Comment: Is it possible that current culture for your system does not provide a       AMDesignator?  Try: `Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`

Comment: The output isn't just missing the AM/PM designation, it's not even close to the format specified in the `ToString` call (e.g. the date isn't yyyy-MM-dd, and the hour isn't padded to 2 digits), so I would suspect something else is going on that you aren't showing.  The code you provided worked fine for me.

Comment: @Codexer I have a class with some properties that I populate previously and one of these properties is a Date Object that I have set by doing DateTime.Now which it provides me a date with AM/PM designator. Later in my code, I read all the properties of this class and extract the properties' information but in case of Date object I need to convert it to a simple string to store it as a field in XML document so for this reason I am trying to convert Date to string.

Comment: @TnTinMn Using Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is working like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: An example with a time in the afternoon would be better because it would be easier to tell if the AM/PM was just being omitted, or if the time was being displayed with hours in the 0-23 range.

Answer (score 2):

This is all in your culture

```
Console.WriteLine(
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", 
                          New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-Us")))

' Output: 2016-03-10 03:42:40 AM

Console.WriteLine(
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", 
                          New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru")))

' Output: 2016-03-10 03:43:01
```